# GetRasterBand()Method for GDAL in Python

Tags: python, gdal, attributeerror

I'm working on getting the NDVI value of Landsat imagery 2018 using band 4 and 5 but I have encountered a slight problem.

```
import osgeo
from osgeo import gdal#gdal, data conversion tool
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import sys
import numpy as np#for reading numbers in python
b8a= gdal.Open('C:\\Users\\zack\\GIS PROGRAMMINGWORKS\\LC08_L1TP_168061_20171228_20180103_01_T1_B5.tiff')             
b4= gdal.Open('C:\\Users\zack\\GIS PROGRAMMINGWORKS\\LC08_L1TP_168061_20171228_20180103_01_T1_B4.tiff')
d8a = b8a.GetRasterBand(1)
d4 = b4.GetRasterBand(1)
```

Error returned:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-cb1cfc43017d> in <module>
 ----> 1 d8a = b8a.GetRasterBand(1)
  2 d4 = b4.GetRasterBand(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'
```

Answer (score 2):

GDAL couldn't open your file and returned `None` instead of raising an exception. And `None`doesn't have a `GetRasterBand` attribute (method or property).

This is a common "[gotcha](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas#PythonbindingsdonotraiseexceptionsunlessyouexplicitlycallUseExceptions)" - *Python bindings do not raise exceptions unless you explicitly call `UseExceptions()`*.

So call `gdal.UseExceptions()` before you try to open the tiff and make sure the path is correct (should the file extension be `.tif`?)